# It is possible to get the index of a combination without generating it?

Tags: algorithm, math

I mean a function that accepts an array of elements and a combination as params, and returns a number that represents the index of a combination without generating every combination.

I have no preference, it can be in any programming language.

An example of code `getCombinationIndex("114")` and should return the index of combination 114.

```
[1,1,1]: 1
[2,1,1]: 2
[3,1,1]: 3
[4,1,1]: 4
[.....]
[1,1,4]: ?
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Can you add more info to this question?  Do you want a function that accepts an array of elements and a combination as params, and returns a number that represents the index of its combination? With which criteria?

Comment: Are you looking for pseudo code or a specific programming language?

Comment: Yes a function that returns the index of a combination an example of code getCombinationIndex("114"); and returns the index of combination 114, without generating every combination

Comment: I have no preference can be in any programming language

Comment: You also need the range of each position.  If the numbers are merely in the range [1,4], then the permutation is merely a mangled version of the integers in base 4.  Reverse the order, subtract 1 from each digit, and convert that number from base 4 to base 10 for your index.  Add 1 if your indexing starts with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "combinations"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you are considering combinations of `k` symbols from alphabet `A = {a_0, a_1, ..., a_n}` (i.e. with `n` symbols and `a_i < a_j` lexicographically if `i < j`). In your example, you  have an alphabet of 4 symbols `A = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and combinations of `k = 3` symbols.

Then, a **combination** `c = [a_i1, a_i2, ..., a_ik]` can be **uniquely encoded** as `I(c) = i1 + n*i2 + (n^2)*i3 + ... + (n^(k-1))*ik`. The indexing you're looking for is `F(c) = I(c) + 1`.

---

Let's see how it works for your example:

```
F([1,1,1]) = I([1,1,1]) + 1 = 0 + 4*0 + (4^2)*0 + 1 = 1
F([2,1,1]) = I([2,1,1]) + 1 = 1 + 4*0 + (4^2)*0 + 1 = 2
F([3,1,1]) = I([2,1,1]) + 1 = 2 + 4*0 + (4^2)*0 + 1 = 3
F([4,1,1]) = I([2,1,1]) + 1 = 3 + 4*0 + (4^2)*0 + 1 = 4
...
F([2,1,3]) = I([2,2,3]) + 1 = 1 + 4*1 + (4^2)*2 + 1 = 38
...
F([1,1,4]) = I([1,1,4]) + 1 = 0 + 4*0 + (4^2)*3 + 1 = 49
...
F([4,4,4]) = I([4,4,4]) + 1 = 3 + 4*3 + (4^2)*3 + 1 = 64
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be seen as base conversion. You need two informations to start with and then it will be only a base conversion.

1. The base 
   In your case this is the highest number of all the items. 
   `[4,1,1] -> 4`
2. The desired combination

This only works for the premiss that all items can have the same maximum.

---

**Algorithm**

1. Reverse the order of items
2. Decrement every item by 1
3. Convert the number to base 10
4. Increment by 1

---

**Example**

1. Start: 114
2. Reverse: 411
3. Decrement: 300
4. Conversion: 
   Base 4: 300 
   Base 10: 3*4^2 + 0*4^1 + 0*4^0 = 24
5. Increment: **25**